# Laravel how to mock SoapClient response for custom validation rule

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Having a custom validation rule that uses the [`SoapClient`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) I now need to mock it in tests.

```php
    public function passes( $attribute, $value ): bool
    {
$value = str_replace( [ '.', ' ' ], '', $value );

        $country = strtoupper( substr( $value, 0, 2 ) );
        $vatNumber = substr( $value, 2 );
        $client = new SoapClient('https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl', [ 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1 ]);
        $response = $client->checkVat( [ 'countryCode' => $country, 'vatNumber' => $vatNumber ] );

        return $response->valid;
    }
```

Used to use [laminas-soap](https://packagist.org/packages/laminas/laminas-soap#dev-develop) package but it doesn't support PHP8. With laminas-soap it was possible to do

```php
$this->mock( Client::class, function( $mock )
{
   $mock->shouldReceive( 'get' )->andReturn( new Response( true, 200 ) );
} );
```

But that doesn't work with `SoapClient::class`.

Then tried from [Phpunit, mocking SoapClient is problematic (mock magic methods)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25302123/phpunit-mocking-soapclient-is-problematic-mock-magic-methods) but also failed:

```php
$soapClientMock = $this->getMockFromWsdl('soapApiDescription.wsdl');
$soapClientMock
    ->method('getAuthenticateServiceSettings')
    ->willReturn(true);
```

Tried from [mock SoapClient response from local XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36406763/mock-soapclient-response-from-local-xml) also failed:

```php
$soapClient->expects($this->once())
        ->method('call')
        ->will(
            $this->returnValue(true)
        );
```

My question is how can I mock a soap response for a custom validation rule that uses `SoapClient`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this [laravel soap](https://github.com/CodeDredd/laravel-soap) package that provides a easy to use `Soap::fake`.

Such as:

```php
Soap::fake(function ($request) {
    return Soap::response('Hello World', 200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
//First you need to pass the client in your parameters
public function passes($attribute, $value $client): bool
...

//Then with phpunit it's possible to do 
public function TestPasses() 
{
    //Replace myClasse with your real class wich contain the passes function
    $myClasse = new myClasse();
    
    $clientMock = $this
            ->getMockBuilder(SoapClient::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(['checkVat'])
            ->getMock();
            
    $reponseMock  $this
            ->getMockBuilder(/*Here it should be the classe returned by the checkVat function*/::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(['valid'])
            ->getMock(); 
            
    $clientMock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('checkVat')
            ->with([ 'countryCode' => /*Put the value you want here*/, 'vatNumber' => /*Put the value you want here*/ ])
            ->willReturn($reponseMock);
            
    $reponseMock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('valid')
            ->willReturn(true /*or false if you want*/);
                  
   $result = $myClasse->passes(/*Put the value you want here*/, /*Put the value you want here*/, $clientMock);

   $this->assertEquals(true, $result);
}
```

Comment: The `passes` method is part of a validation `Rule` that is part of  a `FormRequest` in Laravel and thus only triggered on a create or update action. The custom validation rule is extended from Laravels parent `Rule` class so `passes` method is stuck to those params.